# For an elastic search index, how to get the documents where array field has length greater than 0?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In elastic search index, how to get the documents where array field has length greater than 0?

I tried following multiple syntaxes but didn't get any breakthrough. I got same error in all of the syntaxes.

GET http://{{host}}:{{elasticSearchPort}}/student_details/_search

**Syntax 1:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['enrolledCourses'].values.length > 0",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
"caused_by": {
  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "No field found for [enrolledCourses] in mapping with types []"
}
```

**Syntax 2:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['enrolledCourses'].values.size() > 0",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
"caused_by": {
  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "No field found for [enrolledCourses] in mapping with types []"
}
```

**Syntax 3:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : "doc['enrolledCourses'].values.size() > 0"
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
"caused_by": {
  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "No field found for [enrolledCourses] in mapping with types []"
}
```

**Syntax 4:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : "doc['enrolledCourses'].values.length > 0"
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
"caused_by": {
  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "No field found for [enrolledCourses] in mapping with types []"
}
```

Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of elastic you run, then all my test I'd running on latest 7.9.0 version of Elasticsearch.

I will use painless script for scripting.

I put to documents to index test:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
   "name": "Vasia",
   "enrolledCourses" : ["test1", "test2"]
}

PUT test/_doc/2
{
   "name": "Petya"
}
```

How you can see one document contains `enrolledCourses` field and second not.

In painless you don't need use values field and you can take length directly, this is according to [painless documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-operators-array.html#array-length-operator). Then I skip using `values` operator in my script:

```
GET test/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "script": {
              "script": {
                "source": "doc['enrolledCourses'].length > 0",
                "lang": "painless"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

After running I'd received 2 different errors:

```
{
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "runtime error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType.fielddataBuilder(TextFieldMapper.java:757)",
            "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:116)",
            "org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.lambda$lookup$0(QueryShardContext.java:331)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:97)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:94)",
            "java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:94)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:41)",
            "doc['enrolledCourses'].length > 0",
            "    ^---- HERE"
          ]
}

and
{
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [enrolledCourses] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
}
```

Both of errors is pretty clear. First for document where field doesn't exists and second because Elasticsearch indexed string array field as default mapping type `text`.

Both of cases is very easy to fix by mapping `enrolledCourses` field as `keyword`.
In first case mapping will always provide empty field and in second keyword word be allow to run fielddata property.

```
PUT test 
{
   "settings": {
     "number_of_replicas": 0
   },
   "mappings": {
      "properties": {
         "name": {
           "type": "keyword"
         },
         "enrolledCourses": {
            "type": "keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now I will receive right answer for query:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Vasia",
          "enrolledCourses" : [
            "test1",
            "test2"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```